# Error xmrig en postgres

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Por algún motivo al ejecutar `htop` para monitorear mi servido de base de datos de postgres hay un proceso xmrig que me ocupa el 100% del procesamiento como se muestra en la imagen, sospecho que al ejecutar un querrá se dispara este proceso alguien tiene alguna idea a que se debe.
[image: xmrig ocupa el 100% del procesamiento]

Comment: Tiene pinta de un minado de cryptos, parece que se te colaron al servidor de bse de datos, revisa esto:
https://www.zdnet.com/article/pgminer-botnet-attacks-weakly-secured-postgresql-databases/
https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/pgminer-postgresql-cryptocurrency-mining-botnet/